# getting the width and height of SVG element after skew transformation - javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I have an SVG `rect` with the following atributes:

```
<rect x="50" y="10" width="20" height="30" style="stroke: #000000; fill:none;"  />
```

If I apply a `skewX(10)` tranformation, the width and height of the rectangle change. How do I then calculate its true width and height using plain javascript (without libraries)?

Comment: You're familiar with `Math.sin()` and `Math.cos()` ?

Comment: @StephenThomas I know the basics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the `<rect>` in a `<g>` element; then get a reference to the group; then call `getBBox()` on it.

```js
var  bbox = document.getElementById("wrapper").getBBox();;
alert("width=" + bbox.width + " height=" + bbox.height);
```

```html
<svg>
    <g id="wrapper">
        <rect x="50" y="10" width="20" height="30" style="stroke: #000000; fill:none;"
              transform="skewX(10)" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

The reason we wrap the element in a group is because the bounding box returned by `getBBox()` does not include the effects of the transform.  Also, it doesn't have to be a `<g>` it could be any parent of the `<rect>`, as long as there are no other child elements that could affect the bounds.

Or you could use trigonometry like Stephen suggests.